# Symfony TinyMCE Widget sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE will show code at the end

Tags: symfony1, tinymce

I'm working on my first symfony project (it's great !), i am using the sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE widget for a form in the backend (to display the WYSIWYG).
It works fine, but at the frontend, instead of showing me the formated text, i have the strong,p,... tags in the text.
Same if i paste a youtube code  for example.

Does someone knows how i could solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's for your answer.
Actually i justed used the $object->getRaw()->getValue() method instead of $object->getValue() and i got the "raw" result.
In fact it was properly saved in the database, i just didn't knew how to avoid the auto escaping.

Answer (score 1):

so these strongs and p's... did you create them in WYSIWYG mode on the back end or did you try and paste actual code into the editor? To cut and paste code you need to be in source mode. Other wise you need to use the controls for bold on the tool bar and and line breaks for the p's.

If you used source mode, make sure strong and p are configured to be allowed by tinyMCE - i thought they were by default, but maybe not.